# Using Differentials to Calculate the Volume of a Square Pyramid

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

Use differentials to solve the problem:

The Louvre Pyramid is a tourist attraction in Europe. It is a square pyramid, with a height of $21 m$, and base of side length $35 m$. The four faces of this pyramid are covered in glass, of thickness $0.03 m$. Find the volume of glass used to construct the exterior of the Louvre.

I know that the volume of a square pyramid is: $V=\frac{a^2h}{3}$, where $a$ is its base length and $h$ is its height.

I then solved for $dV=\frac{a^2\ dh + 2ah\ da}{3}$, but I am stuck in this equation because there are many unknowns.

The next step I can think of is finding the volume, which can be in the form of: $V_{Glass}=V(Value+0.03)-V(Value)$, which can be evaluated like: $L(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$, but I am not sure of the way of finding the $V(Value)$.

Comment: If you are not familiar with differentials with two or more variables, then you shouldn't be solving the problem with them. You should first familiarize yourself with them.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning that this problem is a part of my homework, and that I am not that sure if the equation can be altered into a single variable differential.

Comment: Can you find a relationship with the dimensions between $h$ and $a$?

Comment: I think I can use proportions like h/21 = a/35, but I don't know if it would be applicable.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to calculate the volume of the pyramid.  Isn't the volume of glass just $dV?$  $a,h$ are given, so you just need to figure out what $da,dh$ are.

Comment: work out the surface area of a horizontal cross section of the glass, then integrate it from 0 to h.  The glass volume is also going to be the difference between the outside and inside of the glass pyramid

Comment: So, I just need to use dV? But how can I find da and dh without that much given data?

Comment: if the glass is .03 thick, then what length are the sides inside the glass?  And what about the inner and outer height - how are they related?

Comment: How much does the base of the pyramid change when then is added?  How much does the height change?  These are really $\Delta a$ and $\Delta h$ but I take the question to ask for an approximation using differentials.

Comment: So, if the base length is 35, then it will become similar to 35.06 (+0.03 to both left and right sides), which means Δa would become 0.06? And Δh would become 0.03?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you  have many unknown in this formula ? $$dV=\frac{a^2\ dh + 2ah\ da}{3}$$

You have all the information that you need to find your dV.

The only apparently unknown is $d$ which could be found by $$dh=\frac {3}{\sin \alpha} $$ where  $$\tan \alpha = \frac {a}{2h}$$